# How do I get a variable in the superclass for use in the subclass of that superclass?

Tags: objective-c, superclass

Basically, I want to display and utilize a variable that was declared and set in the superclass.

This is the code for setting the variable to its character:

```
- (IBAction)additionSelect:(UIButton *)sender {

    _operation = '+';

    _operationChosenMessage.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You chose %c", _operation];

}

- (IBAction)subtractionSelect:(UIButton *)sender {

    _operation = '-';

    _operationChosenMessage.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You chose Subtraction"];


}
```

This is showing the using of the variable:

```
if([self operation] == '+'){
        if (_firstNumber + _secondNumber == [_writeNumber.text intValue]) {
            _score++;
        }
    }else if ([self operation] == '-'){

        if (_firstNumber - _secondNumber == [_writeNumber.text intValue]) {
            _score++;
        }

    }
    _firstNumber = (arc4random() % 40) - 20;

    _secondNumber= (arc4random() % 40) - 20;



        _displayEquation.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i %c %i", _firstNumber,self.operation,_secondNumber];
```

_operation is a char variable that is declared and set in the superclass(1st snippet), and I want to use it the subclass.

Comment: what does [self operation] supposed to return? I think it is a void method and it return nothing

Comment: a character, either + or -, depending on what button you select in the storyboard before that.

Comment: can you post the code for [self operation] ?

Comment: What is important is how operation ivar/property defined. If base class defines operation property and [auto]synthesizes _operation ivar, there should be no problem accessing it in subclass, assuming it doesn't redeclare operation. Please post your interfaces for both super- and subclass.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you will need to declare a public property in the interface of the class holding the first code snippet (the superclass):

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString *operation;
@end
```

When you declare a property this way, a `_operation` iVar is created behind the scene, and that's why your code like `_operation = '+'` will continue to work as is.   In your subclass, you will be able to access this property anytime using `self.operation`.  If you don't want your subclass to edit that property, you can declare it as `(nonatomic, readonly)`.  Do not add a property with the same name in your subclass as this will override your superclass property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a 'getter' for this somewhere that the subclass can see it.  You might just put it in the superclass' header, or you might make a private header which only some classes import.

Comment: i used @property and tried the method you see above. is that ok? because it still doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't objc still have protected ivars?

Comment: @RahulShah did you declare property in subclass or superclass? If in subclass, then it is synthesized there, thus hiding original ivar.

Comment: I did it in the superclass, because the variable needs to be set equal to a character in the superclass